# set-alias for complex call

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to set an alias for accessing my scheme interpreter. I tried the following:

```
set-alias scheme '& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe" --library "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib"'
```

When calling `scheme` I get the following error message:

```
Cannot resolve alias 'scheme' because it refers to term '& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe" -
-library "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib"', which is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program,
 or script file. Verify the term and try again.
At line:1 char:7
+ scheme <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scheme:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AliasNotResolvedException
```

Calling `& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe" --library "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib"` directly works fine on the other hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alias feature is meant for simple name aliases and doesn't allow for arguments. What you need is a function e.g.:

```
function scheme {
    & "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe" --library "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib"
}
```